# How to change pin color in swift 4.0 in a mapview

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

iOS 11.x Swift 4.0

As far as I can work out this should work, but it doesn't. It compiles, but it doesn't change the color of the pin?

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }
    var view: MKAnnotationView! = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: Constants.AnnotationViewReuseIdentifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if view == nil {
        view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: Constants.AnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
        view.canShowCallout = true
        view?.tintColor = .blue

    } else {
        view.annotation = annotation
    }
    view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
    view.leftCalloutAccessoryView  = UIButton(frame: Constants.LeftCalloutFrame)


    view.isDraggable = true

    return view
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does your view controller have MKMapViewDelegate?

Comment: Yes, it does. It runs past/thru this code and ignores the tintColor it seems.

Comment: Why is view optional for tintColor and it's not for canShowCallout?

Comment: Your right, it doesn't need to be... but also doesn't make any difference still ignored :(

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your ***ViewController*** conforms to ***MKMapViewDelegate*** protocol, replace below line of your code:

```
    view?.tintColor = .blue
```

with this

```
    view?.pinTintColor = .blue
```

**pinTintColor** needs to be set for adding the color. You can read more about **pinTintColor** [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkpinannotationview/1452042-pintintcolor)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nop, pinTintColor doesn't exist in the view?

Comment: At time of dequeuing, you need to deque the pinView as MKPinAnnotationView and not as MKAnnotationView. You can do this as shown below:



            `var pinView: MKPinAnnotationView? = self.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
            if pinView == nil {
                pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            }`